# R: Subset list of data frames by row content? lapply/sapply

Tags: r, subset, lapply, sapply

I have a list of data frames:

```
d1<-data.frame(a=rnorm(5), b=rep(2006, times=5), cc=c(1:5))
d2<-data.frame(a=rnorm(5), b=rep(2007, times=5), cc=c(1:5))
d3<-data.frame(a=rnorm(5), b=c(2005:2009), cc=c(1:5))   #data frame with only one 2007 value
d4<-data.frame(a=rnorm(5), b=rep(2007, times=5), cc=c(1:5))


my.ls<- list(d1, d2, d3,d4)
```

subset only data.frames containing b == 2006

**how to select / subset only a dataframe where** `b == 2007` ?

I am sure that's something simple as

```
my.ls[sapply(my.ls[[i]]$b) == 2007]
```

but I can't figure that out... **How can I access rows in list of data frames?**  Thank you !

---

comparing the results:

```
a1<-Filter(function(x) all(x$b==2007), my.ls)
a2<-my.ls[sapply(my.ls,  function(x) all(x$b==2007))]

> identical(a1, a2)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear whether we need to `subset` the `list` of `data.frame`s with 'b' column having `any` 2007 elements or `all` of them as 2007.  Assuming from the example, it is `all` 2007, we use `Filter` with anonymous function call and wrap `all` around the logical index (`x$b ==2007`) to get a single `TRUE/FALSE` to subset the `list` elements.

```
Filter(function(x) all(x$b==2007), my.ls)
```

---

Or using `sapply`, we loop along the `list` elements and use the same `logical` condition to return a single `TRUE/FALSE` for each `list` element.  Use the `vector` of logical index to subset the `list`.

```
my.ls[sapply(my.ls,  function(x) all(x$b==2007))]
```

Comment: Amazing !! thanks @akrun I am really lost in these apply mapply lapply functions...

Comment: Regarding your question, I have the identical resuts applying both approaches so I don't really see the difference.. I wanted to get back only a data frames where column b contain only 2007. Both suggestions works great on this point. It seems not to work when there is only 1 row with 2007. However, but this is not my case (but I've updated my example) so that works perfectly.  Thank you again !

Comment: @akrun; the same question but in many multivariate time series data, how can I select the range of rows backwards starting from the end of each time series? like each time series data consist of 1970-2004, and I want to select in 1, 3 , 5,..backwards in each time series like ,2004, 2003 and 2004, 2002, 2003 and 2004, how do I do that! thanks!